# Get All Posts from Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for the information posted on the facebook page. I am able to hit the api as below https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/203511053776284/feed?limit=100&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX&format=json. I am able to get the below data but no images related with post.

```
data": [
      {
         "message": "This is my first post",
         "created_time": "2018-05-16T08:05:02+0000",
         "id": "203511053776284_203511440442912"
      }
   ]
```

Any way to get all the information from facebook page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass `fields` value to fetch additional data.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/203511053776284/feed?fields=id,name,message,story,created_time,link,description,caption,attachments{media,type,subattachments}&limit=100&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXX&format=json.
```

I recommend exploring [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) tool.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. Can you please tell me how can I keep the access token alive permanently.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow Permanent User access token. You have to send the user through the login process every 90 days to renew the access token. However Page access token could be permanent. For more in depth go through Facebook doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing & https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: can we get all the comments as well within this api and not calling seperate api for comment